# Bitmaps are being saved to LruCache but they are not obtainable

Tags: android, android-lru-cache

Im caching my Bitmaps in GridView to LruCache. I made manager for this, see below:

```
private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

public LruCacheManager(){
    init();
}

private void init(){

    // Get max available VM memory, exceeding this amount will throw an
    // OutOfMemory exception. Stored in kilobytes as LruCache takes an
    // int in its constructor.
    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

    // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

    //Log.i("ImageCache","cacheSize: " + cacheSize);
    if(mMemoryCache == null){
        mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                // The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than
                // number of items.
                // The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than
                // number of items.
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
                    return bitmap.getByteCount() ;
                } else {
                    return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
                }
            }

        };
    }


}

public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
        Log.i("LruCacheManager","Bitmap is getting added, " + key);
        mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
    return mMemoryCache.get(key);
}
```

when I call `addBitmapToMemoryCache()` in my AsyncTask to save Bitmaps to MemoryCache.

But when i call `getBitmapFromMemoryCache()` its `null`.

```
//get cached Bitmap
    LruCacheManager imCache = new LruCacheManager();
    String imageKey = categoryNames[position];
    Bitmap cachedBm = imCache.getBitmapFromMemCache(imageKey);

    //Decide whatever use cached image or not
    if (cachedBm != null) {
        Log.i("AdapterGridView","Using cached image, " + imageKey);
        viewHolder.icon.setImageBitmap(cachedBm);
    } else {
        //starts Asynctask to scale pictures and show them, happens off the main thread
        new AsyncTaskImageLoader(viewHolder.icon, imageKey, mContext, imCache, mThumbIds[position]).execute();
    }
```

Which means, AsyncTask is called again and again. In AsyncTask im adding the Bitmaps to LruCache. Because returned Bitmap is null, there is no Bitmap saved in LruCache. But i have no clue why.
I also searched online and it has maybe to do something with recycling/Garbage Collector.

So how can i properly load cached images?

Any help or clarification is appriciate.

**EDIT:**

I call this inside BaseAdapter in getView() method. I think it has something to do with it. For the first time, each image is added to Cache, but then, the first image is added like 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

First I would set an arbitrary memory size and try with 1 image. The rest looks good... If what I have below doesn't work, give us printouts of your memory, etc. You might not have any.

In my version I get memory by

```
  final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());
```

then set it by a fraction ( I think I picked an 8th)
I do the /1024 when I return get the size of, I **do not** do it for setting the memory. So if you have 1/1000 of the memory you think you have, that would be the likely issue..

Comment: as @StarWind0 says, that initial cache size is very low. Worked out to 16k on my device. Your bitmaps are probably getting auto-discarded

Comment: Yeah me 3 years later would never use a fraction of max memory. I would down sample the images, then decide on how many I needed at minimum.